# How to get user information using webhook in c#

Tags: c#, facebook, bots, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I'm using api.ai and for webhook visual studo 2015 c# .

I have created some action for some intents and now i'm looking for an action called "welcome.input". I want to get username of the user.
If the user is starting conversation with the bot for the first time i want to give him the possibility to view help menu or standard menu ,
and when the user re-enter in the bot i want to send text : Welcome back {username} and to show him the standard menu.

Have you any idea how to do this.

I was reading https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-State this sample ...but i cannot addapt as webhook in my project.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebhookReceiver.Models;

  namespace FBReceiver.Controllers
    {

public class  facebookController : ApiController
{

    public string Get()
    {
        return "OK";
    }


    public int Get(int id)
    {
        return id;
    }



    public ApiAiResponse Post([FromBody]JObject jsonRequest)
    {
        using (FbReceiverModelDataContext ctx = new 
   FbModelDataContext())
        {
            ctx.spTblTransactions_CreateNew("xyz", "Request", 
   jsonRequest.ToString(), HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

            ApiAiRequest request = jsonRequest.ToObject<ApiAiRequest>();

            ApiAiResponse response = new ApiAiResponse();

            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(request.result.parameters.ToString());
            string xyznumber = (string)jObject["xyznumber"] != null ? (string)jObject["xyznumber"] : "";

            string otherparameter = (string)jObject["otherparameter"] != null ? (string)jObject["otherparameter"] : "";

            if (("action1".Equals(request.result.action.ToLower())))
            {
                tbla a= new tbla();
                a= ctx.tblAa.SingleOrDefault(u => u.a.ToLower() == a.ToLower());

                if (a!= null)
                {
                    response.speech = "a with number " + xyznumber+ " " + a.aaaa;

                    response.source = "aaa";
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xyznumber))
                {
                    response.speech = "Generic info about " + xyznumber;
                    response.displayText = "Generic info about " + xyznumber;
                    response.source = "aaaa";
                }
                else
                {
                    response.speech = "No info";
                    response.displayText = "No info";
                    response.source = "Parcels";
                }
            }



            else if (("pay.info".Equals(request.result.action.ToLower())))
            {
                ///yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            }


            else if (("welcome.input".Equals(request.result.action.ToLower())))
            {

                // to do 

            }


            else
            {
                response.speech = "something is wrong ????";
                response.displayText = "something is wrong ????";
                response.source = "None";
            }




            ctx.spTblTransactions_CreateNew("aaaa", "Response", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response), HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

            return response;
        }
    }


    }
}
```

Please help me . I have many times searching about this topic

Comment: It's not clear what's the issue. Are u using bot framework? Why you can't use the commented code?

Comment: i'm using Api.ai and for webhook i using visual studio 2015 , c#. The commented code isn't ok ... i want your help do get username of user bot and to used it in message

Comment: So you are not using bot framework? Still not clear. Where that code runs? If it's not a bot framework questions please remove the tag

Comment: I agree, this does seem more like 'how to structure the webhook architecture' to communicate between user and bot than a bot framework question

Answer (score 0):

So your question is a little vague, but at a conceptual level what you will need to do is

1. Store some unique user or session ID coming from the messaging integration like facebook messenger
2. Save the associated name with the userID in some kind of Map of key-values, or for a more viable production option in a database. Note that if you want to check if some time has passed since the last message to do some kind of 'welcome back message' based on time gap of messages you will also want to store the timestamp for the latest message
3. On message, check if user exists, if not its a brand new user and prompt for name, if yes run timestamp check to see if coming back after some time away

Here's an example in javascript to demonstrate the approach itself, where you would call this function on receipt of a message from the user, and before passing it to API.ai:

```js
        function setSessionAndUser(messageEvent, callback) {
            var senderID = messageEvent.sender.id;
            var firstTimeUser = false
            if (!sessionIds.has(senderID)) {
                sessionIds.set(senderID, uuid.v1());
            }

            if (!usersMap.has(senderID)) {
                firstTimeUser = true
                database.userData( function (user) {
                    usersMap.set(senderID, user);
                    //Note this is not touching the database and is instead temporarily storing users as a Map in server memory, it's a tradeoff of waiting to touch the DB before replying to every message vs how permanent you need the data to be (and how much data you'll be dealing with)
                    callback(messageEvent, firstTimeUser)
                }, senderID);
            } else{
                callback(messageEvent, firstTimeUser)
            }
        }
```

EDITED TO ADD EXAMPLES FOR 'CATCHING' MESSAGE EVENTS AND THEN PARSING THEM:

```js
//Post to webhook to catch messages
app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
    var data = req.body;

    // Make sure this is a page subscription
    if (data.object == 'page') {
        // Iterate over each entry
        // There may be multiple if batched
        data.entry.forEach(function (pageEntry) {
            var pageID = pageEntry.id;
            var timeOfEvent = pageEntry.time;

            // Iterate over each messaging event
            pageEntry.messaging.forEach(function (messagingEvent) {
                if (messagingEvent.message) {
                    receivedMessage(messagingEvent);
                }
                //Catch all
                else {
                    console.log("Webhook received unknown messagingEvent: ", messagingEvent);
                }
            });
        });

        //Must return a 200 status
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }
});

// Parsing the messageEvent
function receivedMessage(event) {
  var senderID = event.sender.id;
  //...
 }
```

Comment: I can use this function inside   else if (("welcome.input".Equals(request.result.action.ToLower())))
        {
} or i can call this function here ?  Sorry but i am begginer in programming so i make so basic question .

Comment: sorry i'm not clear yet how to use and how to call this function to get username :(

Comment: So your username or whatever unique user identifier you want to store the provided name under will ultimately come from the sender of the message right? Ie facebook messenger will send the user's unique ID number along with the actual body of their message, so first you need to 'catch' these messages, and then parse out the ID from the body.

I'm editing the answer to add examples

Comment: i updated my question with full code ...in to do part i have to add my the code to catch username details and to use in message. The idea is that in api.ai i have to use only one controller.cs as webhook . So for different intents i can use diferent actions. Maybe i am wrong but your code have some problem in my code. I can understand very well your logical but now i cannot express in code :(